# Android Webview app, not work image upload button, nothing happens when tap select image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have created an Android Webview app and it works normally, but when I enter code here` tap buttons which are used to upload a photo, nothing happens. I m attaching my code so you guys can help me out

AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Upload button is not working or any thing else?Please put your code here

Comment: you did not attach any code.